# Copy Cells from a Column to another sheet, only if a cell in the next column is not blank

Tags: excel, vba

So my problem is this:
I have a column that generates OfferCodes (so all cells contain a formula).lets say it's column A.
columns B, C have other data like customer, and issue date etc. 
Column D is OrderConfirmation and the user fills it in (the date) only when the quotation is confirmed.

What I need is to copy (in another worksheet) a list of column A (QuoatationCodes) '(and other columns, but if I know how to do it for 1 column I suppose I will be able to do it for the rest as well)
only if it gets a confirmation date in column D. (basicaly generate an order list where in the new sheet generates unique production-order codes.

What I have now is a list of production-orders with blank rows for the Offers that have not been confirmed)
I need this to refresh automatically/dynamicaly. either on new data entry ( In column D) or by a control button ...

Note that (source) column A will be ever expanding and data entry on Column D (where we have our criteria eg.not blank) is on a daily basis.

Thank you in advance,

Angelos

Comment: Is there some need to use VBA? Seems to me there are various options to do this very simply using standard Excel functionality. You could add a filter to Col D and use it to hide rows with blank values. If you really need to get a copy of the relevant rows into another worksheet, how about creating a pivot table -- drag Cols A, B and C into the "ROWS" of the pivot table; drag Col D into "FILTERS"; deselect "(blank)" from the filter.

Comment: I guess it needs vba, because i cant use the same sheet- yet I have already thought of approaching the whole matter with pivot tables, but i am a newbie at those aswell

Comment: Nothing about pivot tables or filters requires you to use the same sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code. Hope it helps:

```
Sub test()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet
   Dim sh2 As Worksheet
   Dim lastrow1 As Long
   Dim lastrow2 As Long
   Dim j As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim rng As Range

   'set correct name of the sheet with your data'
   Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

   'set correct name of the sheet where you need to paste data'
   Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

   'determining last row of your data in file DEPOT_products.xlsx'
   lastrow1 = sh1.Range("A" & sh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'determining last row of your data in file NewDepotProdsDB.xls'
   lastrow2 = sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'clear content in sheet2
   sh2.Range("a2:d" & lastrow2).ClearContents

   'suppose that in sheet2 data starts from row #2
   j = 2

   For i = 0 To lastrow1

       Set rng = sh1.Range("d1").Offset(i, 0)
       'check whether value in column D is not empy
       If Not (IsNull(rng) Or IsEmpty(rng)) Then
           sh1.Range("a" & i + 1 & ":d" & i + 1).Copy
           sh2.Range("a" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
           j = j + 1
       End If
   Next i
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for your time and answer, but i cannot get it to work.i use option explicit so first i got an error for udefined variable, so i 'dimmed' sh1,sh2 as sheets and lastrow1&2 as range.

Comment: the first set sh1 = ... is still highlighted, and i now get a compile error ( method or data member not found).I am very new to vba so I migth be doing things really wrong.Im trying to use the code in a macro assinged in a control button

Comment: compile error highlights this: ".Rows " in this statement:lastrow1 = sh1.Range("Â" & sh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Thnx ! no errors this time, I am trying to adjust the code to my data... looks promising for now.

Comment: Btw this  code refreshes data every time the macro is run correct?

Comment: Just comment `sh2.Range("a2:d" & lastrow2).ClearContents` line and change `j=2` to `j=lastrow2+1`

Comment: I  am afraid I cant get it to work , just playing around with ranges etc.i get all blank cells copied in a new (test) sheet.And I have also realized that i need sorting as well...I think ill post another question that is more clear and case specific

Comment: i have rephrased my question, trying to make it more clear, kindly check this if you still feel like helping:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899120/copy-and-sort-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-based-on-cell-values

Comment: I have tweaked @simoco's code to work for my spreadsheet, and i have also recorded a macro for sorting afterwards. all this can be seen here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899120/copy-and-sort-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-based-on-cell-values?lq=1 , where the whole issue is more clear, but the answer has been given on this thread form the start.Thank you again!